# Convex hull on set of squares

Tags: computational-geometry, efficiency

Imagine a set of two to six squares within 3D-space. The goal is to generate a convex hull around these squares as efficiently as possible.

The following constraints are known:

- Each of the two to six squares consists out of 4 vertices (a vertex being a 3D-vector). The vertex-data are stored in such a way, that every vertex can be clearly assigned to it's respective square.
- Each vertex is an extreme point of the set (they must all be part of the convex hull).
- During the creation of the convex hull vertices may not be connected to other vertices from within the same square (otherwise the squares would "degenerate").

Is there an especially fast/efficient way to create a convex hull for this very specific geometry?

EDIT: For the sake of clarity, with "convex hull" I actually mean a hull in the sense that all vertices have to be connected to form some way of surface topology (e.g. triangles).

Comment: If there are only $6$ squares, what makes an algorithm inefficient here? Are the numbers that represent the vertices so large that you cannot consider operations on them to be constant time? Why does an ordinary convex hull algorithm for 3D pointsets not work for you here?

Comment: @Discretelizard Your comment gives the impression that in your mind you are equating efficiency with asymptotic growth of the execution time with respect to some size of the input. The latter is only a measure of the former, but not the same. One can can compare the efficiency of different algorithms when solving a single instance of a problem, or a family of instances that has bounded size.

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc Is the second bullet point saying that it is known that all the vertices will be [extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) of the convex hull? If that is the case, you already have the convex hull.

Comment: @plop I asking that question because most of the literature concerns asymptotic complexity and apparently we should look at something different. I'd like to get clarification on what that is.

Comment: @Discretelizard What I wanted to know is, whether this specific arrangement of geometry allows for an implementation that is faster than one that could work on arbitrarily scattered points. Before I invest time on implementing some version of a Graham's Scan or Jarvis-March, I wanted to check if there is some faster/easier way to achieve the desired output.

Comment: @plop Yes, that is exactly what I meant. And yes, technically the set of points is already representing the convex hull. 
However in order to use that convex hull in my application, the points need to be connected by "edges" to form a mesh. Sorry for the bad phrasing of this question...

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc Then my impression is you can do it in time proportional to the number of vertices by maintaining some appropriate datastructures for each square. If you know which vertices are in the same square, just rule them out and connect the vertex with the rest of the vertices. And this procedure is optimal, since we spend constant time visiting each vertex. On the other hand, the problem itself might not be well-defined if you are only given the points without information telling you which vertices are inside each square, since there might be multiple ways to form the squares.

Comment: I see. So, your problem is really determining the [face lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#The_face_lattice) or more specifically the  polytope graph.

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc Ah, then perhaps we could say that rather than efficiency, your main concern right now is _simplicity_ (easy to implement) under the assumptions given here? (of course, the algorithm should also be efficient _enough_, but if I understand you correctly there is no reason yet to rule out standard algorithms on this factor)

Comment: @Discretelizard You are correct, there is no reason to categorically rule out standard algorithms. However I am not looking for the easiest but rather the fastest algorithm, since in my application the desired operation needs to be performed thousands of times.

Comment: @BearAqua I actually do know which vertices belong to one individual square. However I don't think connecting every vertex of every square with every vertex of all other squares would give me a sensible topology...

Comment: I think the complex $O(n \log n)$ divide-and-conquer algorithm would not be faster than the asymptotically slower $O(n^2)$ incremental algorithm, when $n=24$. So just implement (or copy code for) the incremental algorithm.